# Configure TextTemplate Provider to get templated from DB instead of Virtual File System in Abp Framework

Tags: abp

I'm using the new Abp framework and I would like to know if there is a method that I could use to get Scriban templates from a database instead of getting them from virtual file system. In the sample codes the common way of getting templates is placing a directory with the .tpl files. Is there a way to configure a template provider that check a DB for templates? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

there is information here in integrating Scriban:

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Text-Templating-Scriban

It specifically mentions getting the template from another source -

"You can implement the ITemplateContentContributor to read raw template contents from another source."

```
public class MyTemplateContentProvider
    : ITemplateContentContributor, ITransientDependency
{
    public async Task<string> GetOrNullAsync(TemplateContentContributorContext context)
    {
        var templateName = context.TemplateDefinition.Name;

        //TODO: Try to find content from another source
        return null;
    }
}
```